# Since which Android version does it detect internet connectivity on Wi-Fi?

Tags: wi-fi, internet, 3g, 4g

For a project I am working on, I need to connect the phone to a WAN (without internet access) and to the 3G/4G network (to have an internet access).

On my phone (Motorola Moto M 3G, Android 6.0), the phone detect if the Wi-Fi has an internet connectivity and if it doesn't, it keep the 3G/4G for internet and the Wi-Fi for the WAN (which is what I want).

I need to find in which version of Android this functionality (Internet connectivity check on Wi-Fi) has been added to properly test it on the device. I have check all the changelog but I can't find any mention of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Smart Network Switching" is available since Android 5.0.

You can see it in the official changelog [here](https://www.android.com/intl/en_en/versions/lollipop-5-0/#lollipop-feature-7_body) (in "see all features", "connectivity" : «Improved network selection logic so that your device connects only if there is a verified internet connection on Wi-Fi»).

Comment: Well, @benjaminS: actually I was thinking about closing it for being off-topic (development related) – but the fact it's asking for is of interest for "normal users" as well ;) Apart from that: Yes, I 100% agree. Please "accept" your own answer in ~48h+ by ticking the check-mark next to it.